# How to Update an Xml File Android?

Tags: android

I have a layout where users can add buttons and place them where they want. I want to allow the user to save their layout so that it is loaded the next time they open the app. so can i save the updated xml file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to Create layout at rumTime , because you can't edit anything into your xml . all you have is its resource reference R.layout.layout_name ;

So after creating layout RumTime ,  let your user redesign it....and save new coordinates/settings into persistent storage like shared preference or database/file . when later you when  need updated layout pick these settings up and use them .

Comment: Thanks for the help well actually i knew that but wanted to save xml making the app faster it seems i cant thank you anyway